# Large testcases involving graphs in C++ (using STL) throws std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, memory-management, graph, stl, bad-alloc

We are working on a graph (stored as adjacency list implementation) algorithm implementation which requires us to store the following :

1. An 2-dimensional n into n matrix of distances (stored as an array of floats)
2. The number of shortest paths between every pair of vertices (stored as an array of integers).
3. The predecessors for every vertex taking a given vertex as a source vertex, for all possible  choices of source. This is O(n*n*k) where k is the average number of predecessors for a all vertices over all possible choices of source vertex.In the worst case,this can be upto O(n^3) space. However the average number of predecessors is likely to be small.(k is a constant). Predecessor is  stored as a two level map with the list of predecessors stored as a STL vector.

We tried testing on large graphs (>2^12 vertices) and this throws a std::bad_alloc after running for some time. This is the case even when run on 8GB(Ubuntu 12.04) or 16GB using only 3GB of memory. Could you tell how we can get large test cases to work or are we going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Are you using 64bit OS and compiling into 64bit executable?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. _What_ throws `std::bad_alloc`? Are you using `resize` or `reserve` or `shrink_to_fit` to control the `std::vector` capacity? Just letting it grow automatically might reserve nearly double the capacity you actually use. Is a map the best choice of data structure? The pointers between nodes can use a lot of space.

Comment: The pointers between nodes can use a lot of space. Could you elaborate a bit? We have used maps since it takes O(1) to search. What data structure would you suggest for  predecessors? Given a source vertex we only maintain vector of predecessors predecs[s][t]  and every key t may not exist for a given source vertex s.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling your code in 64-bit mode on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: I have used 64 bit operating system and compiled in 64 bit mode.              On typing- file /usr/bin/gedit
/usr/bin/gedit: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, Am I doing this right?